# Git hot-fix to master ends up 2 ahead and 2 behind

Tags: git, azure-devops

I'm new to git so this might be simple, I've created two branches in Visual Studio Online

- Master - With Policies (so pull requests to update only)
- Develop - With Policies (so pull requests to update only)

To do a hot-fix, I created a branch from master called **hotfix**, made the change + synced, and create a pull request to check it into master.

Once the pull request is complete you get the option to cherry-pick that change into a new branch and create a new pull request, which I did to the **develop** branch.

The changes are now in both, but master is now saying it's 2 ahead and 2 behind. This seems wrong.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Can you paste a graph of you git branches here so it is easy for us to guess what might have happened ? Seems like you didn't git pull so you are two commits behind and at the same time didn't git push so you are two commits ahead.

Comment: Thanks, i'm only just back in the office but the post below describes it perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s caused you actually **did no merge `master` into `develop` after completing the pull request merge `hot-fix` branch into `master`**. Instead you cherry-pick the the changes from `hot-fix` branch to `develop` branch.

Let’s illustrate the steps with below graphs (if the `master` branch and `develop` branch commit histories were not as below,  you can also refer below steps since the mechanism are same):

Assume your `master` branch and `develop` branch commit history as below at first:

```
…---A---B---D    develop
         \
          C      master
```

Then you created `hot-fix` and make changes as commits `E` and `F` in below commit history:

```
…---A---B---D    develop
         \
          C     master
           \
            E---F  hot-fix
```

Then create a PR to merge `hot-fix` into `master`, and complete the PR, the commit history will be:

```
…---A---B---D    develop
         \
          C-------G   master
           \     /
            E---F  hot-fix
```

When you cherry-pick the changes (commits `E` and `F`) from `hot-fix` branch to another branch (`develop`), there will create a new topic branch `hot-fix-on-develop` with the changes from `hot-fix` branch on the top of your `develop` branch, and the commit history as:

```
              E'---F'  hot-fix-on-develop
             /
…---A---B---D    develop
         \
          C-------F   master
           \     /
            E---F  hot-fix
```

And if you create the PR to merge `hot-fix-on-develop` branch into `develop` branch, and after completing the PR, the commit history will be:

```
              E'---F'   hot-fix-on-develop
             /      \
…---A---B---D--------G    develop
         \
          C-------F   master
           \     /
            E---F  hot-fix
```

And if you set `develop` as the compare branch, then `master` branch is behind two commits `G` and `D`, and ahead two commits `C` and `F`.

Comment: That's it exactly.So I should have merged Master into development after completing the first pull request? I didn't think i could because both Master and Develop only allow pull requests due to having policies (i know part of a pull request is a merge).

Comment: After completing the first pull request, you should create another pull request instead of clicking cherry-pick.

Comment: I then end up with the master 1 ahead | 1 behind?