# VSTS Git: Is it necesary to resolve dev branch behind/ahead master and if so how?

Tags: git, azure-devops

Let me preface with I am new to Git. I created a POC in VSTS with some code in a Git repo with 2 branches, dev and master. I have branch policies on both; dev enforces squash merging while master enforces no fast forward. I create topic branches for my code changes, then use a pull request to get those into dev, and another to get to master. I understand why my branches show a difference in commits due to the squash merge as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48862162/vsts-and-git-why-does-squashing-my-dev-branch-while-merging-to-master-says-that).

What I don't understand is, is this normal? Do you do any sort of clean up process at the end of your sprint? It seems pointless to have an indicator of differences between branches if the numbers just seem to grow arbitrarily. I've tried to forward and reverse integrate, but they just keep getting further out of synch with each other in terms of commit. From a code perspective they are the same.

Comment: "Is it necessary?" No, you can have two mostly independent branches without any problems. The important measure of differences between branches is given by `git diff`. If this reports no differences, or only differences since the last merge into `master`, then you are okay.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's unnecessary to resolve `dev` branch behind/ahead `master` branch. And you can not resolve it since you are using Pull Request (which execute `git merge --no-ff`).

For the reason why `dev` branch show `X` behind/ahead of `master` is caused by the **no fast forward merge** (`git merge --no-ff`). With no fast forward merge, the source branch and target branch won't point to the same commit even the two branches have same file versions.

And you can also refer the post [Git hot-fix to master ends up 2 ahead and 2 behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47801592/git-hot-fix-to-master-ends-up-2-ahead-and-2-behind/47806855#47806855) for the similar situations.

**BTW:**

> I create topic branches for my code changes, then use a pull request
>   to get those into dev, and another to get to master.

Do you mean the second pull request is merging topic branches into `master` branch?
Actually you'd better create pull request to merge `dev` branch into `master` branch instead of merging topic branches into master branch. This workflow will keep the commit history on `dev` and `master` branches clearly.

Comment: Thank you Marina for your response. Generally we would not merge a topic branch into master, they would merge into dev with a pull request and then dev would be merged into master with a second pull request. The only scenario where a topic branch would merge directly into master would be a hotfix.

Comment: Yeah, that make sense :)