# Branches Ahead/Behind based only on Code Changes

Tags: tfs

For our projects have Integration and Master branch. For deployment we cut a RC branch off Integration. Once deploy is complete we create Pull request for RC to Master.

However, now Master shows as 1 ahead because it has a commit that does not exist in Integration. I considered to create Pull request RC to Integration as well, but TFS does not allow it since there are no changes.

Is there a way to avoid this situation with Master? Can behind/ahead only check the code changes and not commits? To fix this I now have to create Pull Master to Integration, and that is a pain for all the projects we do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afraid not able to avoid this situation. It's also not possible to make behind/ahead only check the code changes and not commits. Since you are using Pull Request (which execute `git merge --no-ff`).

To be honest, **it's not necessary to resolve Integration branch behind/ahead master**.

you can have two mostly independent branches without any problems. The important measure of differences between branches is given by `git diff`. If this reports no differences, then it's Ok.

You could also take a look at this similar question: [VSTS Git: Is it necesary to resolve dev branch behind/ahead master and if so how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49880580/vsts-git-is-it-necesary-to-resolve-dev-branch-behind-ahead-master-and-if-so-how)

If you insist on avoid the ahead on Master, you may have to create Pull Master to Integration as you have pointed out in the question.